# How can I rearrange a multimonitor setup in Kubuntu with the nvidia drivers?

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, xorg, multiple-monitors

Needless to say, nvidia-settings and KDE's display settings aren't working for this.

I have three monitors, one built into my laptop, and two connect via DisplayPort. I wish to rearrange them from their default arrangement.

When I make the appropriate changes in nvidia-settings or KDE's display settings, the changes are not applied. Rebooting just presents me with the same arrangement as I had before.

I know my changes are having some affect, because the login screen is arranged appropriately. It's just when I'm logged in that it seems to be ignoring my settings.

Find below my xorg.conf and the output of `nvidia-settings -q CurrentMetaMode`. Please let me know if there is any other information I should provide. I've been banging away at this for three hours now, and this is my first time trying to configure X, so I'm not very clear on what it is I'm really doing. Thanks!

```
$ nvidia-settings -q CurrentMetaMode
Attribute 'CurrentMetaMode' (serenity:0.0): id=50, switchable=yes, source=RandR
:: DPY-0: 2560x1440 @2560x1440 +0+0 {ViewPortIn=2560x1440, ViewPortOut=2560x1440
+0+0}, DPY-6: nvidia-auto-select @1920x1080 +5120+0 {ViewPortIn=1920x1080,
ViewPortOut=1920x1080+0+0}, DPY-1: 2560x1440 @2560x1440 +2560+0 
{ViewPortIn=2560x1440,ViewPortOut=2560x1440+0+0}
```

---

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 361.42  (buildd@lgw01-18)  Tue Apr  5 14:33:28 UTC 2016

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL P2416D"
    HorizSync       29.0 - 113.0
    VertRefresh     49.0 - 86.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    Option         "DPI" "96 x 96"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro M1000M"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-4"
    Option         "metamodes" "DP-3.1: 2560x1440 +0+0, DP-4: 1920x1080 +1600+1440, DP-3.2: 2560x1440 +2560+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```